# Color associated to ThemeResourceKey

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, colors

I'm trying to retrieve the color associated with a ThemeResourceKey.
This key is got from Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.EnvironmentColors, but it does not cointain explicitly the color information.
Any idea to *extract* the color information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is an extension method called [GetThemedWPFColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vscolors.getthemedwpfcolor.aspx) defined in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0.dll and up (VS2012+) that you can use to get a WPF System.Windows.Media.Color. There are also a couple more extension methods defined in the same class that could help.